# PowerShell - How to process files in folders selected by regex pipeline

Tags: regex, powershell, pipeline

I use the following pipeline to select specific folders:

```
gci -path * | ? { $_.PsIsContainer -and $_.Fullname -notmatch '_' }
```

The above gives me folders that do not have an underscore in their name, which is what I want, and all is good so far.

But when I pipe the result to another `Get-ChildItem`, I get a *BindingException* error:

```
gci -path * | ? { $_.PsIsContainer -and $_.Fullname -notmatch '_' } | gci *.pdf
```

> gci : The input object cannot be bound to any parameters for the command either because the command does not take
>   pipeline input or the input and its properties do not match any of the parameters that take pipeline input.
>
> + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (Book Folder B:PSObject) [Get-ChildItem], ParameterBindingException
>
> + FullyQualifiedErrorId : InputObjectNotBound,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.GetChildItemCommand

How can I process the files within each folder output from the above pipeline.  For example, if a file has a `pdf` extension, I would like to invoke the `Move-Item` command for it.

Comment: `gci | ? { $_.PsIsContainer -and $_.Fullname -notmatch '_' } | gci -Filter *.pdf` should work; please [edit] your question and add a [mcve] of your failing pipe…

Comment: @JosefZ Your answer worked.  I was missing the -Filter argument.  Please post as answer so I can accept.  Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following code snippet outputs fully qualified names of all `.pdf` files in subfolders ***one level*** under current folder that do not have an underscore in their *full path*. (Output file names *could* contain an underscore).

```
Get-ChildItem -Path . | 
  Where-Object { $_.PsIsContainer -and $_.Fullname -notmatch '_' } | 
    Get-ChildItem -Filter *.pdf |
      ForEach-Object { 
        <# do anything with every file object instead of just outputting its FullName <##>
        $_.FullName 
      }
```

You need to use the `-Filter` keyword in the second `gci` with respect to its allowed position **2** (note that position **1** is dedicated for `-Path` parameter).

For further explanation and for potential improvements/optimalisations, read [`Get-ChildItem`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=821580) as well as [`Get-ChildItem` for FileSystem](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/providers/filesystem-provider/get-childitem-for-filesystem?view=powershell-5.1).

Comment: Many thanks for the detailed explanation re: dedicated parameter positions.

Answer (score 2):

Change the last pipeline object

From `gci *.pdf`

To `Get-childitem -Filter *.pdf`

But I would suggest you optimize the total existing line with the below one:

```
gci -path C:\Folder\Path\* -Filter *.pdf | ? { $_.PsIsContainer -and $_.Fullname -notmatch '_' }
```

Comment: I appreciate the optimized version.